# Tabulator - editor list clear value onclick

Tags: tabulator

This is with reference to @christianitis on GitHub closed issue. [click here](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3815) for reference.

When using the "list" editor, clicking the cell will clear the value, and clicking away while the value list is open causes the cell to display a blank value.

The value of the cells is not on the list, would it be possible to set it as is without updating the value? I'm not using the autocomplete editor, just the basic "select".

I'm using the Tabulator 5.4 version.

**Working Example:**

[jsfiddle.net/brx369ef/](https://jsfiddle.net/mrrb/brx369ef/10/)

```
new Tabulator("#example-table", {
columns:[  
        {formatter:"rownum", headerSort:false, hozAlign:"center", width:10 },
        {title:"Status", field:"status", width: 100, 
            editor:"list", 
            validator:function(cell,value){
                if(value.trim() == ""){
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            },              
            editorParams:{ values:["ACCEPTED","REJECTED"],},
            editable: editCheckstatus
        },
  ],
})
```

**Expected behavior:**

It should not clear or return to its current value if not selected a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `mutator` property to call `.getInitialValue()` on the cell when it is cleared. The mutator is also called for the column so you should do this only when `type` is `"edit"`.

For the `validator` you can check whether the cell was empty (cf. the empty cell I added in the code below) before to return false, and return true if either a value is selected from the list or there is an old value available.

```js
new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[  
            {formatter:"rownum", headerSort:false, hozAlign:"center", width:10 },
            {title:"Status", field:"status", width: 100, 
                editor:"list", 
                validator:function(cell,value){
                    if(value.trim() == "" && cell.getInitialValue() == ""){
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                mutator:function(value, data, type, params, component){
                    if(value.trim() == "" && type == "edit"){
                        return component.getInitialValue();
                    } else {
                        return value;
                    }
                },
                editorParams:{ values:["ACCEPTED","REJECTED"]},
                editable: editCheckstatus,
            },
      ],
data: [
  {"status": "ACCEPTED"},
  {"status": "DUPLICATE"},
  {"status": "DELETED"},
  {"status": ""},
  ]
})
```

Comment: The script works as expected! Hope this will implement as a default feature for the basic select editor.